# VSCode can't find the module I've just installed

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, terminal, module, python-3.9

I've just installed a Python module, but VSCode can't seem to find it. I have changed my Python Interpreter, but it doesn't work:

[image]

My code runs fine in the terminal and PyCharm, but when I run it in VScode, it throws an error:

[image]

If you can help me, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just are using the Python interpreter from outside your virtual environment?

Try clicking on the interpreter at the bottom left and check for the one in your env.

[image]